# DNS Server not authoritative for this zone in windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, dns

Every time I try and enter a location on my computer through the command prompt,

e.g. C:\Users\Owner\workspace\swarm

it keeps returning with "DNS Server not authoritative for this zone", what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the folder's on the local machine? Do you have any LANDesk software installed?

Comment: It is on my local machine and I have no software of that type installed.